# Async React Select won't show me the suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using Async React-Select to get some values, the problem is that I receive the data, I can filter it but the result won't appear in the suggestion box.

I've tried different methods, with a filter function without one, I even tried copying some code that I wrote in another app but no luck with that.

This is the code I use for getting the data:

```
getBusinesses = (input) => {
        axios.get(API.GET_BUSINESSES_USERS, {
            params: {
                token: this.props.token
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            const options = response.data.businesses.map(business => ({ label: business.email, value: business.id }));
            this.setState({
                options
            })
            new Promise(resolve => {
                console.log(this.filterOptions(input))
                resolve(this.filterOptions(input))
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

This is the method that filters the data:

```
    filterOptions = (inputValue) => {
        return this.state.options.filter(i =>
            i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
        );
    };
```

And this is how I have the Async Component created:

```
 <Async
   name="form-field-name"
   loadOptions={this.getBusinesses}
   loadingPlaceholder="Cargando..."
   placeholder="Carrera..."
   autoBlur={true}
   clearable={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://react-select.com/async), when using the `loadOptions` prop with a promise, you need to return the promise so that the options can be loaded from the resolved result.

Simply add `return` before your `axios.get` call or change the `{}` to `()` in the `getBusinesses` function to make the `axios` call the return value of the function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it didn't work :(, I'm trying other methods now. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: I change the promise to a callback and now it works perfectly!